# How to insert value into table column which is having spaces php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which name is `data` with column name `First Name`

I am trying to insert data in table but unable to do it as column name is with blank space.

```
INSERT INTO data(First Name) VALUES('Sample');
```

How can i do it, please explain.

Comment: enclose your column name with backtick (`)

Comment: update your query to INSERT INTO data(`First Name`) VALUES('Sample');

Comment: Query should be like this: `INSERT INTO data (FirstName) VALUES ('Sample');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use backticks to encapsulate the field names

```
INSERT INTO data(`First Name`) VALUES('Sample');
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove space from you column name `First Name` should be `FirstName`.

```
INSERT INTO data(FirstName) VALUES('Sample');
```

Or your column contain space then you can use like

```
INSERT INTO data([First Name]) VALUES('Sample');
```