# Cannot insert data in CodeIgniter 3 where database and fields are using space

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, mysql-error-1064

I've tried to insert data using database and table fields where naming the database uses spaces (this is from my office law). But there is a following error -

'Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`harian_copy1` (`RecID`, `id_peminjaman`, `Tanggal`, `Cabang`, `Jenis` `Proyek`,' at line 1'.

Controller:

```
public function inputalokasiharian() {
// Ambil data dari form atau sumber lainnya
    
    $RecID = $this->input->post('RecID');
    $id_peminjaman = $this->input->post('id_peminjaman');
    $Tanggal = $this->input->post('Tanggal');
    $Cabang = $this->input->post('Cabang');
    $Jenis_Proyek = $this->input->post('Jenis Proyek');
    $Nama_Proyek = $this->input->post('Nama Proyek');
    $Kode_Proyek = $this->input->post('Kode Proyek');
    $Jenis_Alokasi = $this->input->post('Jenis Alokasi');
    $Nama_Alokasi = $this->input->post('Nama Alokasi');
    $Jenis_Pekerjaan = $this->input->post('Jenis Pekerjaan');
    $keterangan = $this->input->post('keterangan');
    $persentase_hasil = $this->input->post('persentase_hasil');
    $jam_mulai = $this->input->post('jam_mulai');
    $jam_selesai = $this->input->post('jam_selesai');
    $ketercapaian = $this->input->post('ketercapaian');
    $bagian = $this->input->post('bagian');
    

    $data = array(
        'RecID' => $RecID,
        'id_peminjaman' => $id_peminjaman,
        'Tanggal' => $Tanggal,
        'Cabang' => $Cabang,
        'Jenis Proyek' => $Jenis_Proyek,
        'Nama Proyek' => $Nama_Proyek,
        'Kode Proyek' => $Kode_Proyek,
        'Jenis Alokasi' => $Jenis_Alokasi,
        'Nama Alokasi' => $Nama_Alokasi,
        'Jenis Pekerjaan' => $Jenis_Pekerjaan,
        'keterangan' => $keterangan,
        'persentase_hasil' => $persentase_hasil,
        'jam_mulai' => $jam_mulai,
        'jam_selesai' => $jam_selesai,
        'ketercapaian' => $ketercapaian,
        'bagian' => $bagian
    );

    $this->region_model->insertalokasiharian($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message_input_ah','<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mt-1 fade show" role="alert">Data alokasi harian berhasil dimasukkan
                                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                          </button>
                                                     </div>');
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Model:

```
public function insertalokasiharian($data) {
    $DB2 = $this->load->database('old_db', TRUE);
    return $DB2->insert('`ga - alokasi harian_copy1`', $data);
}
```

Comment: try wrapping the column names having spaces with backticks. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232712/how-to-insert-value-into-table-column-which-is-having-spaces-php-and-mysql

Comment: but how to implement in codeigniter 3?

Comment: something like this '\`Jenis Proyek\`' => $Jenis_Proyek